# Xcode Clear Simulator Environment in XCTest setup

Tags: xcode, xctest

How does one access the simulator environment from XCTest's setup method?  I want to clear the simulator's browser cache and keychain info.

Basically, how do I have my test run on a brand new simulator environment with no previous state?

Can't seem to find it in the documentation.